# Unity building failures & android SDK

Tags: java, android, xml, unity-game-engine, sdk

I have Unity.2017.3.1f1 , JDK 9.0.4 and SDK tool r 25.2.5 when im trying to build the project i am getting this error :

CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Users\nekit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Users/nekit/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[
AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/UnityThemeSelector').

AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/app_icon').

AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').

AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'banner' with value '@drawable/app_banner').

AndroidManifest.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').

]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
Including resources from package: C:\Users\nekit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
applyFileOverlay for layout
applyFileOverlay for anim
applyFileOverlay for animator
applyFileOverlay for interpolator
applyFileOverlay for transition
applyFileOverlay for xml
applyFileOverlay for raw
applyFileOverlay for color
applyFileOverlay for menu
applyFileOverlay for font
applyFileOverlay for mipmap
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

I have tried to install other versions of SDK and im was getting other message "Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct."

what is wrong ? im really new to unity

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because of **(JDK 9)**. You have to install the latest version of **(JDK 8)**, that will fix it. You'll also need to open your Android SDK and install the latest version.